# Calling a function inside a function?

Tags: swift

I have the following function (which uses this awesome [library](https://github.com/vikmeup/SCLAlertView-Swift)) for a button that captures data (copies data) from a cell and then tries to call another function if the user taps imgtagAction. The first button `func buttonViewLinkAction` works great. I get the AlertView and I'm presented with another button `imgtagAction`. However, when I click on that button I get:

> unrecognized selector sent to instance.

```
//get buttonViewLinkAction and copy to pasteboard
@IBAction func buttonViewLinkAction(sender: UIButton) {
    print("buttonViewLinkAction tapped")
    let face = self.faces[sender.tag]
    if let imageNAME: String = String(face.name){
        print(imageNAME .uppercaseString)
    }
    if let imageURL = NSURL(string:face.image) {
        print(imageURL)
    }

    UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = face.directLink

    let alertView = SCLAlertView()
    alertView.addButton("Add [imag] tags", target:self, selector:Selector("imgtagAction:"))
    alertView.showSuccess((face.name), subTitle: "Direct link copied to clipboard")

    func imgtagAction(Sender: AnyObject) {
        print("imgtagAction tapped")
        UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = "[img]" + face.directLink + "[/img]"
    }

}
```

So, when I move the `imgtagAction` function outside of the `buttonViewLinkAction` function I can't get access to the cell data.

```
func imgtagAction(Sender: AnyObject) {
    print("imgtagAction tapped")
    let face = self.faces[sender.tag]
    if let imageNAME: String = String(face.name){
        print(imageNAME .uppercaseString)
    }
    if let imageURL = NSURL(string:face.image) {
        print(imageURL)
    }
    UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = "[img]" + face.directLink + "[/img]"
}
```

The error I get is:

> use of unresolved identifier 'sender'.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Swift is case sensitive.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how that applies to the issue I'm experiencing?

Comment: `sender` vs `Sender`.

Comment: Wow. Of course. Thank you for pointing out that to me, would have never noticed it myself this late into the night.

Answer (score 0):

You have `Sender` instead of `sender`. This is what your function should look like.

```
func imgtagAction(sender: AnyObject)
{
    print("imgtagAction tapped")
    let face = self.faces[sender.tag]
    if let imageNAME: String = String(face.name)
    {
        print(imageNAME .uppercaseString)
    }
    if let imageURL = NSURL(string:face.image)
    {
        print(imageURL)
    }
    UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = "[img]" + face.directLink + "[/img]"
}
```